# Ubuntu Software Center Purchase

Tags: software-center, reinstall

About a year and a half again, I purchased this wonderful game "Machinarium" from Amanita Design at the Ubuntu Software Center. Now, after I got a new Laptop Computer, I wanted to re-install my previously purchased game. However, it is not available anymore in the Software Center. I contacted Canonical Customer Service about this. No answer. I wrote to Amanita Design as well. No answer!

The answer to the marked duplicate question was: "In the Ubuntu Software-Center, go to **File > Reinstall previous purchases** but this did not work for me.

What can I do?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is a rant, not a question.

Comment: @dobey The *customer* is right though. It's not his/her fault the software is no longer available for newer Ubuntu releases. Depending on the license it could be problem. On the other hand so much fuss for an old game available anywhere for $10 or less and it's not even native (GOC and Amanita themselves distribute the Windows version "WINE wrapped" for Linux).

Comment: Yes, but it's not a "question" and not something the community at large could even answer, if it were. The problem is also not limited to Ubuntu. There are games made for Android 2 or 3 that don't work on 6 or 7. It's never great when it happens, but it is live, and I don't think there was ever any guarantees of backward, or forward, compatibility for any _for purchase_ items in the store. Even open source apps may get removed in newer versions of Ubuntu.

Comment: @CelticWarrior Also, I don't think this is a duplicate of that question. This isn't asking _how_ to accomplish that. It's complaining that the software is no longer available, so even knowing _how_, it's simply not possible to do.

Comment: @Lasmahei You *should* be able to find out what is going on with this by contacting Canonical. Specifically how -- and also when -- did you contact their customer service? I recommend you [edit] your question with this information. If there are problems redownloading old app purchases, then I anticipate even more users run may into something like this over time (since paid app purchases through USC are already being phased out). So it might help a lot of people if we figure this out.