# Where have the trusty PPAs gone... and how can I back up current ones?

Tags: 14.04, apt, updates, ppa

When I follow the [instructions](http://www.monodevelop.com/download/) on updating MONO I get a lot of held back packages trying to update:

```
The following packages have been kept back:
  libglade2.0-cil libglade2.0-cil-dev libglib2.0-cil libglib2.0-cil-dev
  libgtk2.0-cil libgtk2.0-cil-dev libmono-2.0-dev libmono-accessibility4.0-cil
  libmono-cairo4.0-cil libmono-cecil-private-cil libmono-cil-dev
  libmono-codecontracts4.0-cil libmono-compilerservices-symbolwriter4.0-cil
  libmono-corlib2.0-cil libmono-corlib4.0-cil libmono-corlib4.5-cil
  libmono-csharp4.0c-cil libmono-custommarshalers4.0-cil
  libmono-data-tds4.0-cil libmono-db2-1.0-cil libmono-debugger-soft4.0a-cil
```

Furthermore in other repos I often don't find Trusty, eg [MonoDevelop 4.0 PPA | launchpad.net](https://launchpad.net/~keks9n/+archive/ubuntu/monodevelop-latest)

or Trusty is the oldest supported (eg [The main PPA for supported PHP versions with many PE | launchpad.net](https://launchpad.net/~ondrej/+archive/ubuntu/php))

The problem is, 14.04 seems to be the last version that had support for purchasing software through Software Center as I recall... If I upgrade how can I backup packages that were bought from Ubuntu Store? It's quite surprising that Ubuntu doesn't want to make money on the store anymore and reading some questions it appears installs may not run after running upgrade:
[Ubuntu Software Center Purchase | Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/872555/ubuntu-software-center-purchase)

Comment: I am having no difficulty updating my 14.04 installation.

Comment: Updating to 16.04? I considered it but I don't know best way to make sure all old purchases are kept.

Comment: I am going to do a clean install to 18.04 when that comes out. I don't have any purchased sw though.

Comment: If I remember right with 14.04 and getting held back applications, I believe you would run `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade` to push those through.

Comment: You didn't say what command you used to upgrade your 14.04.  If you used only `sudo apt-get upgrade` (or apt-get) it has certain rules that limit what can be upgraded.  dist-upgrade as @Terrance suggested is the easiest fix; refer `man apt-get` (searching for 'upgrade' which explains restrictions of upgrade)

Comment: About MonoDevelop - it is available in [their official repository](https://www.monodevelop.com/download/) and [as FlatPak](http://www.monodevelop.com/download/linux/).

Comment: @N0rbert Yes, I have it, it was complaining about newer version project when I was testing it out and I wanted to upgrade it.